# Equality from Definition Riemann Sum

Tags: analysis

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \prod_{i=1}^n \prod_{j=1}^n \left[1+\frac{1}{n^2}f\left(\frac{i}{n},\frac{j}{n}\right)\right]= e^{\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}f(x,y)dydx} $$

After strictly playing around with logarithm and limit properties I was able to get it to the following form:

$$
e^{\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\log\left[1+\frac{1}{n^2}f\left(\frac{i}{n},\frac{j}{n}\right)\right] } $$

which seems like a step in the right direction as it involves sums which are in the riemann sum definition. However, to proceed further I feel I am missing some type of inequality. Any advice is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

So we are left to show that 
$$\tag1{\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\log\left[1+\frac{1}{n^2}f(\tfrac{i}{n},\tfrac{j}{n})\right] } 
=
{\int_{0}^{1}\!\!\int_{0}^{1}f(x,y)\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx}$$
From
$$ e^t\ge 1+t\qquad\text{for all }t\in\Bbb R,$$
we get (using $(1+t)(1-t+2t^2)=1+t^2(2t+1)\ge 1$ for $t\ge -\frac12$)
$$ 1+t\ge \frac1{1-t+2t^2}\ge\frac1{e^{-t+2t^2}}=e^{t-2t^2} \qquad\text{for }|t|<\frac12,$$
and hence 
$$t-2t^2\le \ln(1+t)\le t\qquad\text{for }|t|<\frac12. $$
From this,
$$|\ln(1+t)-t|\le 2t^2\le 2\epsilon^2\qquad\text{for }|t|<\epsilon <\frac12. $$

In order to be Riemann integrable, $f$ must be bounded, say $|f(x,y)|<M$ for all $0\le x,y\le 1$.
Then  for all $n> \sqrt{2 M}$, we have $\left|\frac1{n^2}f(\tfrac in,\tfrac jn)\right|<\frac M{n^2}<\frac 12$
and hence 
$$ \left|\log\left[1+\frac{1}{n^2}f(\tfrac{i}{n},\tfrac{j}{n})\right]-\frac{1}{n^2}f(\tfrac{i}{n},\tfrac{j}{n})\right|\le 2 \frac{M^2}{n^4}.$$
It follows that  the sum on the left in $(1)$ differs from a usual Riemann sum by absolutely at most $n^2\cdot 2 \frac{M^2}{n^4}=\frac{2M^2}{n^2}$, and this tends to $0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: I've been doing analysis quite a while now, so definitely understand the overall proof outline where u show the difference between the left and right hand side becomes infinitesimally small. However, the proof of the inequality ln(1+t)-t < 2t^2 seems almost random to me. Is there a simpler way of showing this inequality?

Comment: I was thinking perhaps one could show this inequality using a taylor series of ln(1+x) (relatively easy to find from geometric series). Then subtract x from this taylor series to show the sum is ultimately less than x^2